# Can't get checkboxes to check and uncheck others

Tags: javascript, html

I need help trying to get some of the checkboxes to check others when they themselves are checked.

i.e. In the JSFiddle link (http://jsfiddle.net/sHKRM/) when the first option 'Milk and Bread' is checked, I need the checkboxes for 'Bread' and 'Milk' to be checked as well as the 'Milk and Bread' box to remain checked.

This needs to be done multiple times on the page (e.g. Chicken and Vegetables should check both of those).

I also need to be able to reverse the selection if the user unchecks.
i.e. If 'Milk and Bread' is ticked, and the two are ticked as a result, they must both become unticked if the 'Milk and Bread' checkbox is unchecked.

I have found various solutions on stackoverflow if the checkboxes were a list, but I cannot get it to work with the rest of the script (once the appropriate items are checked, the user generates the list and then copies it to the clipboard).

As you can see in the fiddle, there needs to be multiple 'combinations' in that a user might want tick 'Milk and Bread' and 'Chicken and Vegetables' so my question is how can this be achieved using the structure I have at the moment (i.e. everything in a table as shown below and not just as a list)?

```
    <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='pe_gen1' value='- Milk and Bread' />&nbsp;Milk and Bread</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='pe_gen2' value='- Bread' />&nbsp;Bread</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='pe_gen2' value='- Milk' />&nbsp;Milk</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='pe_gen2' value='- Cookies' />&nbsp;Cookies</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shameless self-promotion: this looks like a good use-case for [the jQuery-CheckAll plugin](http://mjball.github.com/jQuery-CheckAll/) I've written. You could apply it in this case like so:

```
$('input[value="- Milk and Bread"]')
    .checkAll('input[value="- Milk"], input[value="- Bread"]');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/cL8LL/

Comment: that is a really slick plugin.  Couldn't help but notice how it intelligently selects the `Mild and Bread` if individual `milk` and `bread` checkboxes are selected

Comment: Thanks. Simple behaviors like these are common enough & expected, no one (who's using jQuery, anyway) should need to think about it ever again.

Comment: Thanks for that! For some reason I can't get it to work when I put it into the actual page code: http://jsfiddle.net/sHKRM/4/  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; I tried changing the location of the script but to no avail

Comment: @user1650108 look in the JavaScript console. You've got errors, amigo.

Comment: @MattBall I've tried changing a few things to get it to work, but I can only get it working when I delete the ZeroClip board script immediately after your javascript snippet in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hemang2/WeWQy/ Do you think you could let me know how to resolve (what I assume to be clashes) with the code?

Comment: Your `$` function is shadowing jQuery.

Comment: @MattBall sorry, not quite sure what that means or how to fix it. Tried googling it for some insight but not getting anywhere. Could you explain to me how I can stop this shadowing from happening?

Comment: Use jsfiddle as it was meant to be used. I just renamed the `$` since jQuery uses `$` as well, hence the name clash. Your `$` was stomping out jQuery's. Don't do that. Also, please don't use DOM0 event binding (like `onclick="somefunction()"`). You're using jQuery so do it right. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/38mpY/